# Display background job details on a web page without poling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, delayed-job, ajax-polling

I am updating records from the database using delayed job. i want to display the count of records updated by delayed job on a web page. i can do the ajax polling and can display the count of records updated so far but i think ajax polling is not good way to go since it will add overhead on server.

Is there any alternative of ajax polling.

Comment: yeah its called `websocket` :)

Comment: In web socket can background job in rails send data to web page

Comment: why would you need background job to do this task. better option is to save the count somewhere in the table and proceed if your only concern is to update the webpage with latest number of updated records by `delayed_job`. You can try `ActionController::Live` module, not sure how feasible it is but see if it fits your use case. providing an example below.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try using `ActionController::Live` module from rails.

in your controller:

```
class MyStreamController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live
  def index
    # calculate number of records...
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    response.stream.write "Number of records updated: #{i}"
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

Then in your Js file (may be `application.js`), write a code to point to this url: `/my_stream` to get the updated value. On top of it you can also compare it with previous value and if it has changed then replace the it otherwise ignore it. all can be done using javascript, i'll leave that upto you to figure it out.

example of how to fetch the updated value in js file:

```
$(function(){
  var source = new EventSource('/my_stream');
  source.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log(e); // this is value you want to update on page
  };
});
```

Note: You need to use a threaded server like `puma` etc. to achieve it